# Why does String.IsBOMWhitespace() method always return false?

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET Framework 4.5 the private TrimHelper() method which is called by the Trim() method uses following condition to determine if a character has (not) to be trimmed: (decompiled code by .NET Reflector)

```
if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(this[start]) && !IsBOMWhitespace(this[start]))
```

I am wondering why does the IsBOMWhitespace method always return false??

```
private static bool IsBOMWhitespace(char c)
{
    return false;
}
```

Is this something which Microsoft plans to change/extend in future? e.g. by checking if the char is e.g. '\uFEFF' and return true in that case?

Comment: As the answers show, what you post as if it is the source code isn't the source code. This is generated code obtained by a decompiler, and unless presented as such makes the question very misleading.

Comment: Looks like a side-effect of a bug fix.  An early copy of String.cs available in the SSCLI20 distribution incorrectly classified '\ufeff' as white space.  The comment on that code indicates that this bug was induced by a workaround for a problem with Resgen.exe

Comment: @Hans Passant: Why was it incorrect to classify \uFEFF as white space?

Comment: It is a formatting character, it does not produce visible white space.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks. However they removed much more characters e.g.  '\u200C' from Trim() and this will lead to problems at many customers i believe.

Comment: So this all is because of Unicode backward compatibility: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark "If the BOM character appears in the middle of a data stream, Unicode says it should be interpreted as a "zero-width non-breaking space" (inhibits line-breaking between word-glyphs). In Unicode 3.2, this usage is deprecated in favour of the "Word Joiner" character, U+2060.[1] This allows U+FEFF to be only used as a BOM."

Answer (score 3):

From the source:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,bbf058af7f3f71df

```
private static bool IsBOMWhitespace(char c)
{
     #if FEATURE_LEGACYNETCF
     if (CompatibilitySwitches.IsAppEarlierThanWindowsPhone8 && c == '\xFEFF')
     {
         // Dev11 450846 quirk:
         // NetCF treats the BOM as a whitespace character when performing trim operations.
         return true;
     }
     else
     #endif
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

If the compatibility test `#if FEATURE_LEGACYNETCF` returns true, then you might get a different result.

Comment: But why only NetCF? Framework 3.5 was also treating the BOM as whitespace and not only on NetCF.

Comment: @Kr15 if you look at the comment in the code: `// NetCF treats the BOM as a whitespace character when performing trim operations.` If you think there is something wrong, why don't you raise a support ticket with Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

If you check [the original code source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c):

```
    private static bool IsBOMWhitespace(char c)
    {
#if FEATURE_LEGACYNETCF
        if (CompatibilitySwitches.IsAppEarlierThanWindowsPhone8 && c == '\xFEFF')
        {
            // Dev11 450846 quirk:
            // NetCF treats the BOM as a whitespace character when performing trim operations.
            return true;
        }
        else
#endif
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is just a compatibility feature enabled for the .NET Compact Framework.

Comment: But why only NetCF? Framework 3.5 was also treating the BOM as whitespace and not only on NetCF.

Comment: Thanks but user1666620 was quicker.